# Merging two DataFrames horizontally without reindexing the first

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to stack two DataFrames horizontally without re-indexing the first DataFrame (df1) as these indices contain some important information. However, indices on the second DataFrame (df2) has no significance and can be modified.

I could not find any way without converting the df2 to numpy and passing the indices of df1 at creation. For better understanding please find the below example.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                index=[0, 2, 3,4])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
                'C': ['C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
                'D2': ['D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7']},
                index=[ 4, 5, 6 ,7])

print(df1)
print(df2)
   A   B   D
-------------
0  A0  B0  D0
2  A1  B1  D1
3  A2  B2  D2
4  A3  B3  D3

   A1   C  D2
-------------
4  A4  C4  D4
5  A5  C5  D5
6  A6  C6  D6
7  A7  C7  D7
```

Result I want:

```
   A   B   D   A1   C  D2
--------------------------
0  A0  B0  D0  A4  C4  D4
2  A1  B1  D1  A5  C5  D5
3  A2  B2  D2  A6  C6  D6
4  A3  B3  D3  A7  C7  D7
```

PS: I would prefer a "one-shot" command to achieve this instead of using loops and adding each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the index of `df2` to the index of `df1` and them concatenate the dataframes:

```
df2.index = df1.index
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. I searched for an option for half an hour yesterday. I was using reindex_like() instead of directly replacing the indices without any fruitful result..